# Which information is stored by Google crawler?

Tags: web, web-crawler, information-retrieval

.. and how the web crawler infers the semantics of information on the website?
List out the ranking signal in separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From http://www.google.com/corporate/tech.html:**

**Hypertext-Matching Analysis:** Our search engine also analyzes page content. However, instead of simply scanning for page-based text (which can be manipulated by site publishers through meta-tags), our technology analyzes the full content of a page and factors in fonts, subdivisions and the precise location of each word. We also analyze the content of neighboring web pages to ensure the results returned are the most relevant to a user's query.

Beyond that, your guess is as good as mine.

Answer (score 1):

- Semantic Closeness as a Ranking Signal
- Site Traffic, # visitor, trends

Ranking factors - http://www.vaughns-1-pagers.com/internet/google-ranking-factors.htm

Answer (score 0):

I guess noone really knows, that is a trade secret:)

Comment: Though its trade secret, its answer may be available to google index only :)